# Color rows alternatingly according to change in column value – without hidden columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel sheet with multiple columns, where in one column subsequent values can be identical or different, so that the rows form a number of groups. I would like the rows belonging to a group to be coloured alternatingly.

So for example, in a table

```
A         B
species   name
unicorn   Toni
unicorn   Fred
lorax     Harry
cerberus  Alex
cerberus  Jeff
mandrake  Liz
mandrake  Suzi
mandrake  Anna
```

I would like "unicorn" rows to have a green background, "lorax" row white background, "cerberus" rows green background, etc.

I have a solution using additional columns (which can be hidden):

- create another column C, with the formula `=INT(A2=A1)` in C2 and copied to C3 and following
- create another column D, with the formula `=ISEVEN(SUM($C$2:C2))` in D2 and copied to D3 and following
- apply conditional formatting to all cells in A and B based on `$D2`

My question is: Can this be done without additional columns, or at least with only one?

Comment: I'm not sure of the purpose of your formulas, you can directly code all of your conditions in "conditional" formatting.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? There's a `UNIQUE()` function in newer version that you can use to count how many unique items there are in a range. That could be used to jump straight to what you have in the helper column D (`=ISEVEN(COUNTA(UNIQUE(A:A)))`) and *that* could be used directly in the conditional formatting. If true, then green. If false, then white (or maybe vice versa).

Comment: @gns100, great, how?

Comment: @EngineerToast unfortunately I'm stuck on Excel 2007. Your idea makes sense, but doesn't seem to work in my version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this in the conditional formatting formula:

```
=ISEVEN(SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH($A$1:$A1,$A$1:$A1,0),MATCH($A$1:$A1,$A$1:$A1,0))>0,1)))
```

... and the inverse `=NOT(ISEVEN(...))` for the other colors.

I did not write this from scratch. I found it via a web search. [Here's the page](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/count/count-unique-values-excel#:%7E:text=Count%20Distinct%20Values%20using%20Formulas) I used.

All I did was modify the range to be `$A$1:$A1` so it will automatically apply to everything from row 1 to the current row. You may need to modify this range if your Refers To range doesn't start with row 1 (or your data isn't in column A) but it seems you're already comfortable with that.

Comment: I upvoted but did not accept yet because when I first tried it it worked, but then I wanted to make a change, deleted the rule and made it fresh, and then Excel became unresponsive. Is it possible the formula works in principle but can consume a lot of CPU?

Comment: @A.Donda If you apply the conditional formatting to an entire column then yes, the formula can become CPU-intensive. `FREQUENCY()` and `MATCH()` both look at huge blocks of data and we have 3 of them here. Newer versions of Excel have functions that can do the same as above but in a faster, simpler format which, I imagine, is kind of the point of the new functions.